# can't get animated text to show inside div

Tags: jquery

I am almost where I need to be. I am trying to match this flash header [here](http://www.abbingtonpartners.com/) using jquery. Here's what I have so far [link to sample](http://northshorewebdesign.net/jm-demo/index2.html) the problem starts when I try to have the text slide in from the right. It ends up near the bottom of the document. I tried absolute and relative positioning in different combos but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
    // JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrap").css({
        'width':'900px',
        'margin':'0px auto', 
        'height':'150px', 
        'background':'#333',
        'overflow':'hidden'
        });
        // css for first text
    $("#text1").css({
        'position':'relative',
        'margin':'0px auto',
        'text-align':'center', 
        'color':'#fff', 
        'font-size':'140px',
        'top':'-120px', 
        'opacity':'0.5'
        });
        // animate first text
    $("#text1").animate({
        'top':'150px'           
        }, 3000, 'linear');

        // css for second text  
    $("#text2").css({
        'position':'relative',
        'margin':'0px auto',
        'text-align':'center', 
        'color':'#fff', 
        'font-size':'140px',
        'bottom':'-80px', 
        'opacity':'0.5'
        });
        // animate second text
    $("#text2").animate({
        'bottom':'330px'
        }, 3500, 'linear');

        // css for third text   
    $("#text3").css({
        'position':'relative',
        'margin':'0px auto',
        'text-align':'center', 
        'color':'#fff', 
        'font-size':'60px',
        'right':'0px', 
        });
        // animate third text
    $("#text3").animate({
        'right':'160px'         
        }, 3000, 'linear');

});
```

The id is text3. sorry i couldn't get the code to format correctly.

Comment: Try absolute positioning.

Comment: I would suggest not using JavaScript to set base CSS.  Use a .css file.  It will make your code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your #wrap a position of relative then your moving text inside of it a position of absolute. It should cause you less headaches.

Comment: ok, I tried that but now text2 id doesn't show and text1 id is no longer centered.

Comment: sorry, missing an 'n' on position. Text still not centered

Answer (score 0):

Without a setting top in the css, it's being pushed down by the other stuff:

```
 #text3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 150px;
 }
```

You're going to also want to redo this with #wrap having a position:relative, as any right and left movements will be based off the window, so using px values will make it look different depending on window size.  #text3 is about 315px wide so you'll want to set it at right:-315px to start.

Comment: nearly there. just can't seem to center the large text that enters first